# .fetchall() character chinese characters on terminal

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, character-encoding

I want get the database's result from the **new_all** on Terminal，but it show likes this

> [(None, None, u'', 0, None, None, None, u'1000', None), (u'test', u'', u'', 801, >u'2014-09-05', None, None, u'10010000', 1),"……

How to convert it to chinese in order to work out what **new_all**'s meaning.
My Terminal as shown in the images。
Database is msSQL, odoo is OK.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAFoU.png)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models, fields, api, _
from openerp.exceptions import UserError
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import pymssql
class service_sync_wizard(models.TransientModel):

    _name = 'service.sync.wizard'

    @api.multi
    def service_sync(self):
        logger.debug('wqeqwretfdasffc')

        or_conn = pymssql.connect(host="116.224.93.245", port="1433", user="sa", password="frp992", database="vsale",
                              charset='utf8')
        or_cur = or_conn.cursor()
        or_cur.execute("""select contact,phone1,phone2,id_oper,reg_date,addr,memo,cust_id, id_val from cust c
        where c.oe_flig is null or c.oe_flig = 'FALSE'""")
        new_all = or_cur.fetchall()
        logger.debug('new_all is %s'% new_all)
```

Comment: You propably didn't use terminal with UTF-8 encoding
try change it: Terminal -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Char - Encoding and set UTF-8

Comment: The Terminal can show chinese character...

Comment: What kind of collation do you have on your database? Run it: SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('dbname', 'Collation') SQLCollation